# Would a library installation question fit SO better than SU?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, migration, superuser, scope

I feel that [my question at Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/254552/how-do-i-install-pyopenssl-on-windows-7-64-bit) doesn't get enough attention, am I targeting the wrong public?

Is it fine for Stack Overflow that I ask to migrate this question there? Or aren't these type of Qs allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a fair number of Scrapy questions on SO already, so this probably fits. Not saying you'll get an answer there either, but it's probably worth a shot. I would remove your question from SU though if you do post on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the irony of there being no answers to your question yet :)

It looks like a reasonable question for SO, especially since you form your questions intelligently.